# What is the best way to add users to multiple groups in a database?

Tags: sql, database

In an application where users can belong to multiple groups, I'm currently storing their groups in a column called `groups` as a binary. Every four bytes is a 32 bit integer which is the `GroupID`. However, this means that to enumerate all the users in a group I have to programatically select all users, and manually find out if they contain that group.

Another method was to use a unicode string, where each character is the integer denoting a group, and this makes searching easy, but is a bit of a fudge.

Another method is to create a separate table, linking users to groups. One column called `UserID` and another called `GroupID`.

Which of these ways would be the best to do it? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship between users and groups. This calls for a separate table to combine users with groups:

```
User: (UserId[PrimaryKey], UserName etc.)
Group: (GroupId[PrimaryKey], GroupName etc.)
UserInGroup: (UserId[ForeignKey], GroupId[ForeignKey])
```

To find all users in a given group, you just say:

```
select * from User join UserInGroup on UserId Where GroupId=<the GroupId you want>
```

Rule of thumb: If you feel like you need to encode multiple values in the same field, you probably need a foreign key to a separate table. Your tricks with byte-blocks or Unicode chars are just clever tricks to encode multiple values in one field. Database design should not use clever tricks - save that for application code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely go for the separate table - certainly the best relational view of data. If you have indexes on both UserID and GroupID you have a quick way of getting users per group and groups per user.

Answer (score 1):

The more standard, usable and comprehensible way is the join table. It's easily supported by many ORMs, in addition to being reasonably performant for most cases. Only enter in "clever" ways if you have a reason to, say a million of users and having to answer that question every half a second.

Answer (score 0):

I would make 3 tables. users, groups and usersgroups which is used as cross-reference table to link users and groups. In usersgroups table I would add userId and groupId columns and make them as primary key. BTW. What naming conventions there are to name those xref tables?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're trying to do, but if your database supports it, you might consider using roles.  The advantage of this is that the database provides security around roles, and you don't have to create any tables.